# How do I present a view controller from UISearchViewController embedded in a child view controller of a parent view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, childviewcontroller

I have a parent view controller called MainViewController, and a child view controller called FilterViewController that takes partial of the main controller screen.

Inside the filterViewController I added a UISearchController to the tableview. But When I click on the search result to go to DetailViewController

`Attempt to present <MyApp.DetailViewController: 0x7f97ae057780>  on <MyApp.FilterViewController: 0x7f97abd62b40> which is already presenting <UISearchController: 0x7f97abd85270>`

I am using this on iPad iOS 8 simulator.
If the resultSearchController is not active I can click the table and it goes to whatever I present, but somehow this uisearchcontroller won't allow me, what is a workaround to this?

Code:
MainViewController.swift

```
   func addFilterViewController(){
    filterViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("filterviewcontroller") as! FilterViewController
    filterViewController.mainViewController = self
    self.addChildViewController(filterViewController)
    filterViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width*2/3, 0, self.view.frame.width/3, self.view.frame.height)
    self.view.addSubview(filterViewController.view)
    filterViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

FilterViewController.swift

```
func setUpSearchBar() {
    resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

    let searchBar = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightBlue()
    searchBar.placeholder = "Type to search"
    filterTable.tableHeaderView = searchBar
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if resultSearchController.active {
        println("search table select")
        let detailVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("detailViewController") as! DetailViewController
        detailVC.card = filteredCards[indexPath.row]

        // this has same problem if I pass in the MainViewController and do mainViewController.presentViewController...
        self.presentViewController(detailVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

    } else {
        // other code
    }

    filterTable.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.filteredCards = self.unorderedCards.filter{
        (card: Card) -> Bool in
        let name = card.firstName + card.lastName
        let stringMatch = tributeName.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchController.searchBar.text.lowercaseString)
        return (stringMatch != nil)
    }
    filterTable.reloadData()

}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  if resultSearchController.active {
       return filteredCards.count
   } else {
       return unOrderedCards.count
   }}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("filtercell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FilterCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightBlue()
    if resultSearchController.active {

        let card = filteredCards[indexPath.row]
        cell.name.text = card.firstName

    } else {
        let card = unOrderedCards[indexPath.row]
        cell.name.text = card.firstName
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is the view controller is yet presenting resultSearchController, why not let resultSearchController present the new vc?

```
resultSearchController.presentViewController(detailVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Then, if you need to make the dismiss from resultSearchController, just create a new class inheriting from UISearchController.